# Faking inheritance in C: Will alignment break my neck?

Tags: c++, c, inheritance, casting, alignment

I have a C struct that is used in various **C and C++** code (via `extern "C"`).

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

  typedef struct A A;
  struct A {
    /*some members*/
  };

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Allocation, initialisation and release is done by separate member functions under my control, but I do not control access to members, as they are accessed all over the place.

The trouble is, I cannot change the `struct`'s definition in the header that is heavily used throughout the system, but I still want to extend the type and add some members. Since this must compile as both C++ and C, I cannot simply create a derived type `struct B : public A`. So my idea was to add this type to the cpp file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

  typedef struct B B;
  struct B {
    A parent; // <---- public inheritance
    /*some members*/
  };

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Now, I can modify all functions in the cpp file but I still have to hand out and accept `A*` outside of the compilation unit as nobody knows what `B` is.

So, I'm wondering if there is a sane and well-defined way of doing this. Can I simply cast my `B*`s to `A*s` and back or would it I have to explicitly convert them:

```
A* static_cast_A(B* b) {
  return &(b->parent);
}
B* static_cast_B(A* a) {
  B* const b = 0;
  unsigned const ptrdiff = (unsigned)((void*)(&(b->parent)));
  return (B*)(((void*)a)-ptrdiff);
}
```

**Are there any more problems with this or should I do it differently altogether?**

Comment: `#include <stdalign.h>` and `struct alignas(A) B { ... };`

Comment: @oldrinb: That sounds interesting, could you extend it as a proper answer? I cannot seem to find any portable examples on the web.

Comment: it's a well-defined part of the C11 standard. It ensures `B` uses the same alignment as `A`.

Comment: Sadly, C11 is not widely in use yet...

Comment: @oldrinb: Ah yes, now I found it too. However, this not portable in C++ (as the compiler support for C++11 is not available on all platforms) nor would this work in C.

Comment: @bitmask it will work with any C++11 or C11 compliant compiler.

Comment: If you are using the structures from C code, you could use functions to access all fields in the structures. Then just pass a `void*` around for the structure, and typecast it to the proper objects in the member access functions. This way you can use full C++ in your own code, while still allowing it to be used from C (and other languages that uses the C ABI).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Well, there is already code that accesses `A` and I have no control over it. My extension must be invisible to that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alignment requirements shouldn't cause any problems, and this is indeed the default way to fake inheritance in C.

However, your `static_cast_B()` is not portable (in particular `void *` arithmetics and conversion to `unsigned` in case of `sizeof (void *) > sizeof (unsigned)` - the latter should still work, but is something of a code smell).

I suggest using the following code instead:

```
#include <stddef.h>

B* static_cast_B(A* a) {
  return (B*)((char*)a - offsetof(B, parent));
}
```

Comment: I believe even simple C cast shall work: `B* static_cast_B(A* a) { return (B*)a; }`. I do not have access to C++ and C std(s) but I am pretty sure there is zero offset in first member of POD struct.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: using `offsetof()` makes multiple-inheritance possible - you could have a `parent_foo` and `parent_bar`, and only one of these can be the first member

Comment: @Christoph Agree. I thought only about this particular case with single inheritance.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: I have single inheritance, but I like to be on the safe side. The compiler will optimise it out, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you don't introduce a virtual table (by adding a virtual method or destructor) in `struct B` and `parent` member of that struct is the first element, then it is safe to just case `B` to `A`.

Casting `A` to `B` is safe, too, but only if the original pointer is actually pointing to `B` and not to something else, like only `A` structure itself, obviously.

In case when `parent` is not the first member of struct `B`, you would have to use `container_of` macro as seen in Linux kernel, for example. It works off the member pointer offsets (i.e. some good explanation can be found [here](http://open-nandra.com/2009/08/container_of-macro-or-how-it-works/)).

Also, by default both structs will have the same alignment. I am not sure how the compiler would place `A` into `B` if you tweak one of the structs alignment. I guess that is compiler dependent, but should be easy to figure out.

If `B` has a virtual table, you must know compiler internals to convert the pointers correctly. For example, `GCC` on x86_64 adds 8 bytes offset thus you have to offset it manually when converting. But that won't work in case of virtual inheritance (virtual base classes), to solve that you have to resort to using RTTI etc... But this is outside of the scope of your question and I'd recommend you don't go that way.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The `container_of` macro seems to do basically what I did with my casts, doesn't it?